# OpenGL ES large delay between 'onDraw()' calls

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm creating a live wallpaper using openGL ES and I've run into trouble getting my wallpaper to remain over 30fps.

One thing I've noticed is that if I completely empty my `onDraw()` method (apart from a bit of timing code) the `onDraw()` method is getting called only every ~11ms when the rendermode is set to 'continuous'.

This seems a little odd. Especially when I add in some polygons and textures, the code then takes only a few extra ms between frames.

my code:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {          
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long dt = endTime - startTime;              
    Log.v("time",Long.toString(dt));
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
}
```

Is this normal behaviour? perhaps there is something going on behind the scenes.

I've tried messing around with my setup code, but it doesn't seem to change anything

**traceView** seems to suggest that `EGLImpl.eglSwapBuffers` seems to be taking around 45% of the execution time with a `0.633` cpu/call. The code shown above takes up about 25%, with the next highest entries being `Thread.sleep()`.

EDIT - I think that swap buffers is synced with the display refresh rate which would explain what I'm seeing.

Comment: Have you tried using DDMS traceview to profile it? That's a pretty good way to find out what's taking time in your application.

Comment: good point. I'll update my question

Comment: I'd consider not worrying about the 'completely empty' case that you've posted, and try to profile your full blown rendering to see why you're falling under 30fps. There may be some things like vsync or a frame limit cap imposed by glsurfaceview that are obscuring what's really going on. For example my renderer never goes above 60fps no matter how much work I give it. 11ms is 90fps, and SwapBuffers will always take a couple ms, but you should have a lot of headroom before you get to 30fps.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've done that already and I think it's simply a case of me trying to do too much. It works well above 30fps except for responding to touch events or when the phone gets woken up and is probably doing lots of other things too. I'm not sure if I can avoid the delay in this case. I was kind of hoping I could reclaim 10ms from somewhere but It doesn't look as though that is the case.

Comment: Actually, I've tested some other live wallpapers on the market. It seems as though they all lag on touch events. It's actually quite noticeable on move events if you continue to try and scroll once you've reached the limit. Thanks for the advice by the way :)